# How would I group values in a field based on range of number using python, and then update the attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, grouping

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish is described below, however they don't describe how to use the data update cursor to update the attribute column.

data - Group values based on range of number in python - Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437394/group-values-based-on-range-of-number-in-python

```
fc = r'C:\Users\Test.gdb\Test1a'
print "fc set"
class_field = "Numbers"
name_field = "GroupedID2"
lst = sorted(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [class_field,name_field]))
class Delta:
    def __init__(self, delta):
        self.last = None
        self.delta = delta
        self.key = 1
    def __call__(self, value):
        if self.last is not None and abs(self.last - value[0]) > self.delta:
            # Compare with the last value (`self.last`)
            # If difference is larger than 2.5, advance to next project
            self.key += 1
        self.last = value[0]  # Remeber the last value.
        return self.key

import itertools
for key, grp in itertools.groupby(lst, key=Delta(2.5)):
    for tup in grp:
        print(tup + ('project{}'.format(key),))
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "GroupedID2") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        print (row[0])
```

The trouble that I have is that no matter where I place the update cursor, I can't get it to record each row correctly.  It will make the entire attribute the last project number or the first project number instead of rows 1-3 project1, 4-6 project2, and 7-8 project3.

This is what the code prints.  The feature class remains project 1 but it isn't updated to include the correct project number from the 3rd column.

```
2014-07-16 07:26:59.135000
fc set
(1279015.0, u'project1', 'project1')
(1279017.5, u'project1', 'project1')
(1279020.0, u'project1', 'project1')
(1279022.5, u'project1', 'project1')
(1279027.5, u'project1', 'project2')
(1279030.0, u'project1', 'project2')
(1279032.5, u'project1', 'project2')
(1279037.5, u'project1', 'project3')
(1279040.0, u'project1', 'project3')
(1279042.5, u'project1', 'project3')
```

when I alter the code to read this:

```
import itertools
for key, grp in itertools.groupby(lst, key=Delta(2.5)):
    for tup in grp:
        print(tup + ('project{}'.format(key),))
        test = ('project{}'.format(key))
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "GroupedID2") as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                test = row[0]
                cursor.updateRow(row)
                print (row[0])
print(datetime.now()-startTime)
```

It still keeps it as project 1.

Comment: If you aren't already familiar with using cursors, then coming up with a solution will be tough. Do you understand how the accepted answer works, at least?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question so that it includes a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck, please?

Comment: I posted the code.  Yes, I understand how cursors work.  I just can't seem to maintain all of the project numbers that the code comes up with for the respective rows.

Comment: it should be row[0] = test and not test = row[0], but test is not modifiied while you are using your cursor, so you will have the last test value of your for tup in grp as output. your should use a whereclause when you create your update cursor in order to select only the values that are within your range.

Comment: @radouxju Ok, so I made changed it to row[0] = test, and you were right.  That did make it give the last test value as the output for the whole row.  My question is, how would you format the where clause to get a range?  My experience with where clauses is getting the max of a value and type of another value.

Comment: @radouxju Would there be a better way to export the first set of printed information to a dbf table even though it's a tuple?  Then I could just join the table back to the feature class based on the number.  (1279015.0, u'project1', 'project1')
(1279017.5, u'project1', 'project1')
(1279020.0, u'project1', 'project1')
(1279022.5, u'project1', 'project1')
(1279027.5, u'project1', 'project2')
(1279030.0, u'project1', 'project2')
(1279032.5, u'project1', 'project2')
(1279037.5, u'project1', 'project3')
(1279040.0, u'project1', 'project3')

Answer (score 1):

here is an alternative to your solution

```
#store field values in a new list
newlist=[]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("valueField")) as scursor:
    for row in scursor:
        newlist.append(row[0])

#find the boundaries between classes
newlist.sort()
limits=[0]
for j in range(newlist):
    if (newlist[j+1]-newlist[j])>2.5:
        limits.append(newlist[j+1])

#update project number inside the boundaries 
for i in range(len(limits)-1):
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ("GroupedID2"), """ ("valueField" >={0}) and ("valueField" <{1}) """.format(limits[i], limits[i+1]) ) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0]='project{}'.format(i)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I tried both of these codes, and the error messages say that floor, minimum, and maximum need to be defined.  How do they need to be defined?

Comment: sorry, I didn't specify. floor is a function, but you need to import math module. Minimum and maximum must come from previous code, or manual inputs.

Comment: It still gives the same error when I say import math or from math import *

Comment: I used the floor example and got this in the attribute table:1279015 project0
1279017.5 project1
1279020 project2
1279022.5 project3
1279027.5 project5
1279030 project6
1279032.5 project7
1279037.5 project9
1279040 project10
1279042.5 project11

Comment: isn't it what you need ? if the difference is 2.5 advance to the next project, this it what my code does. You can change the value of the step if you want.

Comment: It should group them by the difference of 2.5 with the same project number.  It advances if it is over 2.5.  For example it should read: 1279015 project1 1279017.5 project1 1279020 project1 1279022.5 project1 1279027.5 project2 1279030 project2 1279032.5 project2 1279037.5 project3 1279040 project3 1279042.5 project3

Comment: OK, now I get it. I've completely edited my code. It could be more "Pythonic", but it should work like you want.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like we're getting closer.  I got the error, 'newlist' is not defined.  What should it be defined as?

Comment: newlist is a list. I have edited my post. Hope this work, this is my last try.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive. +1!